# Configure Load Balancer as broadcaster

Tags: amazon-elb, azure-load-balancer, google-cloud-load-balancer

This may be a naive question so please bear with me. :)

In the below diagram, there is a load balancer in front of 3 instances...

Is it possible to configure the load balancer (ELB/Google Load Balancer/Azure load balancer...basically any) to forward/broadcast every request to all instances...
If not load balancer, what component natively provided by IaaS providers can broadcast such requests to all instances?

[image]

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151042/is-it-possible-to-send-a-broadcast-message-to-all-instances-behind-the-elb), but it was from 2016 and was hoping if anything changed?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed. The purpose of a Load Balancer is to **distribute traffic**, not to broadcast traffic.

The closest AWS service that matches your diagram is **Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS)**.

It uses a public/subscribe model:

- An Amazon SNS **Topic** is created
- Various **subscriptions** can be attached to the topic (Email, SMS, AWS Lambda, HTTP endpoint, Amazon SQS queue)
- A **message** is sent to the topic and it is forwarded to all subscribers

[image: Amazon SNS]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/images/sns-how-works.png))</sub>

See: [What is Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html)